# Django templates not executed in a container and no errors displayed in the logs

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm running django 2.1.3 in to a python3 container based on alpine image, I create my own image by following this guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ (with other project works) this time the templates are not showed, the page I receive is the render of the called template the extends part are not present.

I try to run code in a bind folder instead docker volumes and had no change.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir -p /code/
WORKDIR /code/
ADD requirements.txt /
RUN apk update && \
 apk add postgresql-libs && \
 apk add --virtual .build-deps gcc musl-dev postgresql-dev && \
 python3 -m pip install -r /requirements.txt --no-cache-dir && \
 apk --purge del .build-deps
```

docker-compose (django image section):

```
django:
  build: "./django"
  image: registry.gitlab.com/vaschetto.marco/project-docker-File/django:v0.1
  container_name: Project_django
  restart: always
  command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  env_file:
    - ./django/.env
  volumes:
    - django:/code/
    - django_static:/code/static/
  depends_on:
    - psql
```

Template structure:

```
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── Dockerfile
├── project
...
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── sito #app
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
...
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
...
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── sito
│   │       ├── body.html
│   │       ├── footer.html
│   │       ├── head.html
│   │       └── home.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── static
```

django project settings (installed apps and template section):

```
...
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'sito',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
...
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
...
```

project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('sito.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

sito/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

sito/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here
def index(request):
    return render(request, "sito/home.html")
```

sito/templates/sito/home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                {% block head %}
                {% endblock %}
        <head>
        <body>
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
        </body>
        <footer>
                {% block footer %}
                {% endblock %}
        </footer>
</html>
```

sito/templates/sito/head.html:

```
{% extends "sito/home.html" %}
{% block head %}
<title>
        This is the title WEBISTE!
<title>
{% endblock %}
```

sito/templates/sito/body.html:

```
{% extends "sito/home.html" %}
{% block body %}
        <h1>WEB SITE BODY!</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

sito/templates/sito/footer.html:

```
{% extends "sito/home.html" %}
{% block footer %}
        <h2>THIS IS THE FOOTER</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

the result I expect is some think like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>
                This is the title WEBISTE!
            <title>
        <head>
        <body>
            <h1>WEB SITE BODY!</h1>
        </body>
        <footer>
            <h2>THIS IS THE FOOTER</h2>
        </footer>
</html>
```

but the render return this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>

        <head>
        <body>

        </body>
        <footer>

        </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html templating part is conceptually wrong. You ask to render the `home.html` has place holders for the content. You have to fill those placeholders by extending the template and override them before rendering, since you didnt override them they stay empty thats why you see empty html blocks. You have defined header and footer by never used them inside a template. Try below approach, you can extends how you want it after understood correctly. Its pretty simple.

- header.html => only header content
- footer.html => only footer content
- base.html => define the structure of the html page, include the header and footer here
- home.html => extends from the base.html and override the `block body`

  ```
  ====== sito/header.html =======
  <title>
      This is the title WEBISTE!
  </title>

  ====== sito/footer.html =======
  <h2>THIS IS THE FOOTER</h2>


  ====== sito/base.html =======
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          {% include "sito/header.html" %}
      <head>
      <body>
          {% block body %}
          {% endblock %}
          <footer>
              {% include "sito/footer.html" %}
          </footer>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Now you can create html templates by extending the `base.html`

```
    ====== sito/home.html =======
    {% extends "sito/base.html" %}
    {% block body %}
        <h1>WEB SITE BODY!</h1>
    {% endblock %}

    ====== sito/about.html =======
    {% extends "sito/base.html" %}
    {% block body %}
        <h1>This is About us</h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand where I went wrong in the extension logic; I had implemented as per you suggestion, but I think I make some error more, now all HTML code is in the title :( the result is: (take a look here: http://vmhome.ml )

Comment: I had a wrong markup for the footer check with edited base template, should work

Comment: I was already invert the header, footer include and the footer tag inside the body, but no changes, now all code are printed inside the header, looks like it is look for an end tag in the title file.

Comment: Yes i saw now end title tag is not closed, I have fixed in the template(header.html) `<title> needs to be </title>`

Comment: Greate, now is show correctly header and footer.. but the extends still not show up! it is like {% block body %}{% endblock %} are ignored by django!

Comment: Which page you are rendering? base.html or home.html?

Comment: in the view.py the rendered page is base.html

Comment: Ok, I get the problem, is my flow of templates in django was completelly wrong

Comment: Dont render base.html, its still has placeholders! render the home.html or about.html

Comment: Yes, now I get it, I realize now if I render the base.html how templates engine could know what I want? No reference to the page, thanks a lot for your help! It makes me clear the template engine workflow (hope definitively) :)